# How to fix a Blender 2.8 file when open with 3.5?

Tags: library-overrides, proxies

I've recently bought a new computer and therefore went on using Blender 3.5 instead of 2.8. And some of my file are not living the transition well.
I think it's due to the proxy system (which I kind of understand) having been replaced by override collections (which I don't).

The result is that some objects are displaced and, mainly, the proxies I used are now multiplied and every copy is unaffected by the animation.

[image]

What you see above is my cop character with his head offset on the left and sharing his space with, like, 5 copies of him stacked upon eachother and not moving.
Blender won't let me delete the static copies because of the library override system.

I don't either know what to do or want to start over.
How can I get pass this ?

You can download my file here : https://we.tl/t-ju9CkRmztR